# How to disable Outlook temporarily (Windows XP, Office 2007)?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

We are migrating dozens of computers from WindowsXP, and it would help if there is a way of disabling Outlook usage while backing-up users files. Is there a proper way to do it?

Comment: When you say disable you mean so people not able to launch it why not ask them?

Comment: Because its impossible to ensure dozens of users will obay, remember, or pass info to other colleagues working on the same computer.

Answer (score 1):

use group policy to control access to the software

[Software restriction policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786941(v=ws.10).aspx)

If all you have is dozens of users then I would consider this waste of time